# Mule ESB JDK 1.8 memory tweaks

Tags: mule

We are planning on using `JDK 1.8` for `Mule 3.7 CE`.

In the past we edited wrapper.conf to tweak the memory `JDK 1.6/1.7` uses. We did this by editing:

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=256m
wrapper.java.maxmemory=512
wrapper.java.additional.7=-XX:PermSize=256m
wrapper.java.additional.8=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Looking into the processes that are running in `linux` we see that Mule still uses `xmx` settings. If not mistaken, this no longer works in `java 1.8` because it has been removed. Instead `JDK 1.8` uses metaspace.

Now my question is, how/where to we make memory tweaks for `Mule 3.7` using `JDK 1.8`? Or does `Mule 3.7 CE` not support this yet?

Do we simply add to wrapper.conf the following settings?:

```
wrapper.java.additional.16=-XX:MetaspaceSize=100M
wrapper.java.additional.17=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2024m
```

And remove:

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=1024
wrapper.java.maxmemory=1024
```

Or we do still use the following settings?

```
wrapper.java.initmemory
wrapper.java.maxmemory?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please upvote the answers. This makes their ranking better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep using the initmemory and maxmemory. 
Changing to Java 1.8 doesn't impact this.

We use Java 1.8 with Mule 3.7 in Linux and we are able to successfully control the heap allocation with the current setting of initmemory and maxmemory.

You might want to use Metaspace configuration only to replace PermGen settings.

```
wrapper.java.additional.16=-XX:MetaspaceSize=100M
wrapper.java.additional.17=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2024m
```

Go through the following link for more understanding.
http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-PERMGEN-Removed

Hope this helps.